# Add an overlay to a react-navigation navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to add an overlay (e.g. to display error popups/toasters/debug buttons etc) to a [react-navigation](http://reactnavigation.org) navigator.

However I have a problem:

When I put the react navigator **in a view**, with the overlay on top, the react navigator either doesn't appear or is distorted in some way.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
   title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>;
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

class SimpleAppWithOverlay extends React.Component {
  render() { 
    return( 
      <View>
        <View style={{position: "absolute", backgroundColor:"transparent", margin:30}}>
           <Text>Some Overlay</Text>
        </View>
        <SimpleApp/> 
      </View>);
  }
}
```

Here are two snippets showing what I mean in a live editor:

- Basic react navigation setup: https://snack.expo.io/ryI4oCvQW
- Same, but with an overlay attempt: https://snack.expo.io/HkSgoCDX-

You can see in the second example, the overlay appears but the underlying app is just not visible.

Can this work? How?

Comment: Stupid question I know but is your overlay background transparent and are you positioning it above the basic layer with `position:'absolute'`?

Comment: @MilanGulyas Thanks - Stupid questions still helpful!! :) I *was* using `position:absolute`, but *not* `backgroundColor:transparent`. However I've tried that https://snack.expo.io/HyzBWWdQW and the react navigator is still not showing. So if I'm not doing something stupid (my first assumption), perhaps it is doing something clever - in which case the question is - how do we out-clever it?

Comment: Can you edit the question above with the relevant code in it? It is pretty hard to guess without that.

Comment: @MilanGulyas np I've added the code in the question and the `snack` links have the code in a live editor so you can see the output

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Changed your code a bit

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Welcome',
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Hello, Navigation!</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

class SimpleAppWithOverlay extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <SimpleApp />
        <View style={{ position: "absolute", backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,0,0,0.4)', top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }}>
          <Text style={{ paddingTop: 8 }}>Some Overlay</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const SimpleApp = StackNavigator({
  Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('overlayapp', () => SimpleAppWithOverlay);
```

You should note that `position: 'absolute'` is only positioning relative to the parent not absolutely absolute like in css.

If you want to overlay above the navigationBar you can probably do something similar with navigationOptions.headerRight.

Comment: Is it possible to overlay the navigator itself or only the screen?

Comment: In my real example I have lots of routes, not just the one, and I want to have an overlay at the top level (e.g. a little floating debug button when in dev mode).

Comment: I see now why you wanted put the homepage inside the overlay.  It should be possible if you render the SimpleApp inside the overlay. Will change the code when I can.

Comment: I changed the code to have even the navigation bar under the overlay. It is really close to what you where doing, I think if you add `flex: 1` your most outer view you would get a similar result. I tried earlier to include even the notification bar as well, but didn't find a way to do that. The closes was controlling the color with StatusBar.

Comment: Ah great! Thanks so much.