# Make a specific screen transparent react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to make a specific screen have a transparent background using react navigation but I only want this behaviour on this specific screen. I am stuck because I have tried the following approach:

```
export const MainNavigator = StackNavigator({
  ScreenOne: {
    screen: ScreenOne
  },
  ScreenTwo: {
    screen: ScreenTwoNavigator
  },
  ScreenThree: {
    screen: ScreenThreeNavigator,
  },
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  mode: 'modal',
    cardStyle: {
      opacity: 0.1,
   },
})
```

However, this results in the opacity being applied to all the screens. I have also tried removing the opacity from this and instead setting it within the ScreenThreeNavigator, which contains only the single screen that i wish to have as transparent. This had no impact whatsoever. I have also tried setting the background color of the View for this screen as transparent but this also did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by instead taking this approach and not using a separate screen:

[Add an overlay to a react-navigation navigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44675175/add-an-overlay-to-a-react-navigation-navigator)